# Removing image via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Very recently I have started programming and I'm currently running into an issue to which I hope you can help:

- Ajax executes the upload.php page which succesfully deletes the file from the server and from the MySQL table
- The Ajax result however is an error message and the image is not removed from **Page.php** unless reloaded.

**Page.php**

```
    <div class="row no-collapse 50% uniform">
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SubEntries_SQL)) {
        $fileURL = "upload/" . $_SESSION['adminID'] . "/" . $row['filename'];
        $fileId = $row['id'];
        $fileName = $row['filename'];
        if (!file_exists($fileURL)) {  $fileURL = $sub_entryThumbURL = "../../images/no_img.png"; }

    ?>                          

        <div class="2u" id="success">                   
            <span class="image fit 50%">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="RemoveItem('<?=$fileId;?>','<?=$fileName;?>')">
                    <img src="<?=$fileURL;?>" border="0" class="thumb" />
                </a>
            </span>
        </div>

    <?php
    }   
    ?>
    </div
```

**Ajax function**

```
    function RemoveItem(itemId,ItemName) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'content/upload.php', 
            'type': 'POST',
            'data': {itemId: itemId, name: ItemName, request: 2}, 
            'success': function(data) {
                 if (data == 1) {
                    $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
                }
            },
            'error': function () {
                alert("error");
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: There is no class `.success`, only multiple elements with id `#success`. You need to get rid of the duplicate id's and target the right `.success` element. Using the jQuery `onClick` handler instead of the inline one, would make that easier.

Answer (score 2):

There is a confusion inside the while, here's my suggestion:

1. Where you have  replace the id="success" for a unique id and common class

Assuming your $fileId is unique among all nodes

```
<div class="2u delete_success" id="#delete_<?php echo $fileId; ?>">
```

By doing this you'll get distinct nodes, next step would be to make your javascript to know which node to delete after completion.

The ajax function would be something like.

```
function RemoveItem(itemId,ItemName) {
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'content/upload.php', 
        'type': 'POST',
        'data': {itemId: itemId, name: ItemName, request: 2}, 
        'success': function(data) {
             if (data == 1) {
                $("#delete_"+itemId).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            }
        },
        'error': function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Changed the line: `$("#delete_"+itemId).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);`

This should do the work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This put me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction! Final code that I used to get the desired result:

/* jQuery */

```
function RemoveItem(itemId,ItemName) {
$.ajax({
    'url': 'content/upload.php', 
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': {itemId: itemId, name: ItemName, request: 2}, 
    'success': function(data) {
        $("#delete_"+itemId).html( data );
        /*$("#delete_"+itemId).fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);*/
    },
    'error': function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

/* Html */

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($SubEntries_SQL)) {
    $fileURL = "upload/" . $_SESSION['adminID'] . "/" . $row['filename'];
    $fileId = $row['id'];
    $fileName = $row['filename'];
    if (!file_exists($fileURL)) {  $fileURL = "../../images/no_img.png"; }

?>                          
    <div class="2u" id="delete_<?php echo $fileId; ?>">     
        <span class="image fit 50%">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="RemoveItem('<?=$fileId;?>','<?=$fileName;?>')">
                <img src="<?=$fileURL;?>" border="0" class="thumb_step1" />
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>

<?php
}   
?>
```

/* upload.php */

```
$targetDir = "upload/";

if($request == 2){
    $filename = $targetDir.$_POST['name']; 
    mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM $upload_db WHERE filename = '".$_POST['name']."'");
    unlink($filename);
}
```